# Reading multiple csv files in a single dataframe

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a lot of compressed csv files in a directory. I want to read all those files in a single dataframe. This is what I have done till now:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with gzip.open(path+"/"+filename, 'rb') as f:
        temp = pd.read_csv(f, names=col_names)
    df = df.append(temp)
```

I have noticed that the above code runs quite fast initially, but it keeps on getting slower and slower as it reads more and more files. How can I improve this?

Comment: what's your files extension `.tar.gz` or `.gz` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest file extension is `.gz`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Ultimate optimization

- avoid calling `pd.DataFrame.append` function within a loop as it'll create a copy of accumulated dataframe on **each** loop iteration. Apply [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate pandas objects at once.
- no need to `gzip.open` as [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) already allows on-the-fly decompression of on-disk data.

  > **compression** : {‘infer’, ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘zip’, ‘xz’, None}, default ‘infer’
- avoid hardcoding filepathes with `path+"/"+filename`. Instead use suitable [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) feature: **`os.path.join(dirpath, fname)`**

---

The final optimized approach:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dirpath = 'path_to_gz_files'   # your directory path
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dirpath, fname))
                for fname in os.listdir(dirpath)], ignore_index=True)
```